# Excel VBA building a formula from variables

Tags: excel, vba, formula

My apologies for such an easy question.  I have googled this to death, and I can't figure out why this won't work.  I just want to add a new row and insert a formula into a cell.

My code is this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lStr As String
    Dim nRow As Long
    Dim nStr As String

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    lStr = CStr(lRow)
    nRow = lRow + 1
    nStr = CStr(nRow)

    Cells(nRow, 1).Value = Date
    Cells(nRow, 2).Value = ""
    Cells(nRow, 3).Value = 25
    Cells(nRow, 4).Value = 53
    Cells(nRow, 5).Select
    ActiveCell.formula = "=IF(AND(C" & nRow & "=""""|D" & nRow & "="""")|""""|E" & lRow & "-C" & nRow & "+D" & nRow & ")"

End Sub
```

I've tried using the string value of the row in the formula (using nStr instead of nRow, etc).

If I remove the "=" sign at the beginning and put it as a value, it inserts, and if I then add the "=" via excel it evaluates fine, so I know the format of the formula as a string is fine.

But why won't it insert the formula?

I've also tried doing it in r1c1 notation.

Any ideas?

Note, the values 25 and 53 are temporary values.  The end user will be manually entering values into those cells.

Comment: Replace the `|` with comma `,`.  vba is very US English centric and the formulas must be entered as standard US English format.

Comment: Wow.  That worked.  So if I enter =IF(AND(C6=""|D6="")|""|E5-C6+D6) into the cell manually, it works, but through VB I need to use =IF(AND(C6="",D6=""),"",E5-C6+D6).  THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that even though

```
=IF(AND(C6=""|D6="")|""|E5-C6+D6)
```

works if you manually enter it into a cell, through VB you need to replace the pipe symbol with a comma.  So changing my formula to

```
ActiveCell.formula = "=IF(AND(C" & nRow & "="""",D" & nRow & "=""""),"""",E" & lRow & "-C" & nRow & "+D" & nRow & ")"
```

solved the problem